# JSON parsing in iOS, give me "null"

Tags: ios, json

I have this JSON and I want to parse.

```
"entry"[
        {"id" { },
        "published" { },
        "content"   { },
        "link" [5], {       "rel": "something",
                            "type":"other stuff",
                            "href":"http://www....",
                            "title":"TITLE..",
                            "thing":"something"
                    }
        },

        {"id" { },
        "published" { },
        "content"   { },
        "link" [5], {       "rel": "something",
                            "type":"other stuff",
                            "href":"http://www....",
                            "title":"TITLE..",
                            "thing":"something"

                    }
        .......
        }


    ]
```

I'm doing something like this:

```
NSDictionary* dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableArray *NewsArrayTMP = dataDictionary[@"feed"][@"entry"];

for (NSDictionary *vDictionary in NewsArrayTMP)
{
    News *news = [[News alloc] init];

    news.publishedNews= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"published.$t"];
    news.updatedNews= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"updated.$t"];
    news.contentNews= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"content.$t"];   
    news.linkForShare= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"link.href"];

    [self.Newsrray addObject:news];
}
```

In this way, I get all the "href" in the array. I would get, for example, the 4th.

I'm trying this too:

```
news.linkForShare= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"link.href.[4]"];
```

But the string is `null`.

I've also tried this:

```
news.linkForShare= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"link.href.4"];
```

But I'm wrong with something. How I can do this?

Comment: The JSON already looks invalid tbh

Comment: Yeah, from here... http://jsonlint.com it's invalid (after removing the ..........)

Comment: Whatever you think this is, it is not JSON. It is something that has a very slight resemblance to what would happen if a clueless web programmer made his first attempt to create JSON, but it isn't JSON. It's not just invalid, there isn't the slightest bit that is valid about it.

Comment: Thanks,sorry i try to explane better.
the json is correct, i just toke a piece of it.
    news.linkForShare= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"link.href"];

but in this way i get the "href" of all 5.

    "link" [5], {       "rel": "something",
                            "type":"other stuff",
                            "href":"http://www....",
                            "title":"TITLE..",
                            "thing":"something"

if i would get the 4th for example? how i can get ti?
     news.linkForShare= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"link.href.[3]"];  ?
so doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: That's rubbish. It's not JSON. It's not a piece of JSON. It's not even a good attempt at pretending to be JSON. If you have something that _is_ JSON then post it.

Comment: That's right gnasher729, later i'll post the correct json.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the json:

```
{
```

"feed": {

```
"entry": [
  {
    "id": {
      "$t": "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-64444540.post-341089429"
    },
    "published": {
      "$t": "2014-05-01T09:00:00.000+02:00"
    },
    "updated": {
      "$t": "2014-05-01T09:00:07.017+02:00"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "$t": "Bocce \" rinforzo giusto”"
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "html",
      "$t": "<div class=\"MsoNormal\"><br /></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><br /></span></div><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"celvetica, sans-serif;\"><b><i><br /></i></b></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><br /></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">” </i></b></span><br /><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><b><i><a href=\"httpsa></i></b></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><b><br /></b></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">></span></div><br /><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><br /></div>"
    },
    "link": [
      {
        "rel": "replies",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "http://test.blogspot.com/feeds/45432259045304590/comments/default",
        "title": "Comments"
      },
      {
        "rel": "replies",
        "type": "text/html",
        "href": "http://test.blogspot.com/feeds/45432259045304590/comments/default.html#comment-form",
        "title": "0 Commenti"
      },
      {
        "rel": "edit",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "ttp://test.blogspot.com/feeds/45432259045304590/comments/default/45432259045304590"
      },
      {
        "rel": "self",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/32432432442/posts/default/534464793232329"
      },
      {
        "rel": "alternate",
        "type": "text/html",
        "href": "http://test.blogspot.com/2014/05/testpaginadacercare.html",
        "title": "Bocce ”"
      }
    ],
    "author": [
      {
        "name": {
          "$t": "IO"
        },
        "uri": {
          "$t": "http://www.blogger.com/profile/0232131232132321"
        },
        "email": {
          "$t": "noreply@blogger.com"
        },
        "gd$image": {
          "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail",
          "width": "32",
          "height": "32",
          "src": "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/3442/3434435ff/hhhhf4435345/ffd44-p0/s1000/*"
        }
      }
    ],

    "thr$total": {
      "$t": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "$t": "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-64444540.post-341089429"
    },
    "published": {
      "$t": "2014-05-01T09:00:00.000+02:00"
    },
    "updated": {
      "$t": "2014-05-01T09:00:07.017+02:00"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "$t": "Bocce \" rinforzo giusto”"
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "html",
      "$t": "<div class=\"MsoNormal\"><br /></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><br /></span></div><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"celvetica, sans-serif;\"><b><i><br /></i></b></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><br /></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">” </i></b></span><br /><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><b><i><a href=\"httpsa></i></b></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><b><br /></b></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">></span></div><br /><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><br /></div>"
    },
    "link": [
      {
        "rel": "replies",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "http://test.blogspot.com/feeds/45432259045304590/comments/default",
        "title": "Comments"
      },
      {
        "rel": "replies",
        "type": "text/html",
        "href": "http://test.blogspot.com/feeds/45432259045304590/comments/default.html#comment-form",
        "title": "0 Commenti"
      },
      {
        "rel": "edit",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "ttp://test.blogspot.com/feeds/45432259045304590/comments/default/45432259045304590"
      },
      {
        "rel": "self",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/32432432442/posts/default/534464793232329"
      },
      {
        "rel": "alternate",
        "type": "text/html",
        "href": "http://test.blogspot.com/2014/05/testpaginadacercare.html",
        "title": "Bocce ”"
      }
    ],
    "author": [
      {
        "name": {
          "$t": "IO"
        },
        "uri": {
          "$t": "http://www.blogger.com/profile/0232131232132321"
        },
        "email": {
          "$t": "noreply@blogger.com"
        },
        "gd$image": {
          "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail",
          "width": "32",
          "height": "32",
          "src": "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/3442/3434435ff/hhhhf4435345/ffd44-p0/s1000/*"
        }
      }
    ],

    "thr$total": {
      "$t": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "$t": "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-64444540.post-341089429"
    },
    "published": {
      "$t": "2014-05-01T09:00:00.000+02:00"
    },
    "updated": {
      "$t": "2014-05-01T09:00:07.017+02:00"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "$t": "Bocce \" rinforzo giusto”"
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "html",
      "$t": "<div class=\"MsoNormal\"><br /></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><br /></span></div><div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a href=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"celvetica, sans-serif;\"><b><i><br /></i></b></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><br /></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">” </i></b></span><br /><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><b><i><a href=\"httpsa></i></b></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><b><br /></b></span></div><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">></span></div><br /><div class=\"MsoNormal\"><br /></div>"
    },
    "link": [
      {
        "rel": "replies",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "http://test.blogspot.com/feeds/45432259045304590/comments/default",
        "title": "Comments"
      },
      {
        "rel": "replies",
        "type": "text/html",
        "href": "http://test.blogspot.com/feeds/45432259045304590/comments/default.html#comment-form",
        "title": "0 Commenti"
      },
      {
        "rel": "edit",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "ttp://test.blogspot.com/feeds/45432259045304590/comments/default/45432259045304590"
      },
      {
        "rel": "self",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/32432432442/posts/default/534464793232329"
      },
      {
        "rel": "alternate",
        "type": "text/html",
        "href": "http://test.blogspot.com/2014/05/testpaginadacercare.html",
        "title": "Bocce ”"
      }
    ],
    "author": [
      {
        "name": {
          "$t": "IO"
        },
        "uri": {
          "$t": "http://www.blogger.com/profile/0232131232132321"
        },
        "email": {
          "$t": "noreply@blogger.com"
        },
        "gd$image": {
          "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail",
          "width": "32",
          "height": "32",
          "src": "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/3442/3434435ff/hhhhf4435345/ffd44-p0/s1000/*"
        }
      }
    ],

    "thr$total": {
      "$t": "0"
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

now i post the code that works and how i get the date:

```
NSMutableArray *NewsArrayTMP = dataDictionary[@"feed"][@"entry"];

for ( NSDictionary * vDictionary in NewsArrayTMP)
{

    News *news= [[News alloc]init];

    news.titleNews= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"title.$t"];
    news.dNews= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"id.$t"];
    news.publishedNews= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"published.$t"];
    news.updatedNews= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"updated.$t"];
    newsBlogSpot.contentNews= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"content.$t"];

        ////// HERE THE PROBLEM
    newsBlogSpot.linkForShare= [vDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"link.href"];
```

the problem is on the last line, because i want to get the "href:" of the 4th "link:"

like i do, i get the "href:" of all "link:".
i hope that i have been clear.
Thanks

Comment: i resolved in this way: 
news.linkForShare = vDictionary[@"link"][4][@"href"];
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

JSON requires a : between the key and the value, so you need to go through your JSON and modify it like this

```
{
  "entry": [
     {
       "id": {}
      }
  ]
}
```

and so on.  You can run your JSON through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.org) to help you validate it.

Also, you don't need the `[5]`s

Comment: Not "You don't need the [5]s", but they will stop it from working. [5] would be a JSON array with a single element that happens to be the number 5.

Comment: Of course, you're correct. I'm assuming that the asker will take the initiative to figure things out once he has the right idea and has been pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You are an optimist :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your dataDictionary as NSArray instead of NSDictionary.
You should get your dictionaries as element of the array.

NSArray* dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];